# bitmap by diceroll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, bitmap

How would you go about Rolling a dice and display the corresponding die face bitmap

some quick and efficient code examples?

```
void CMFCApplication12Dlg::OnBnClickedDiceroll()

    {  
       int die1 = 1 + rand() % 6; // first die roll
       int die2 = 1 + rand() % 6; // second die roll
       //display die1 & die2
    }
```

//
    void CMFCApplication12Dlg:: OnPaint handler ()

```
{
//load the image file
    CString szFilename("C:\\Talla\\yourimg.bmp");
    HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL,szFilename,
    IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

//Create a Bitmap Object and Attach It to the Object
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Attach(hBmp);

// Create a Memory DC and Select the BMP to It
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CDC bmDC;
    bmDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = bmDC.SelectObject(&bmp);

//Get the BMP Height and Width 
    BITMAP bi;
    bmp.GetBitmap(&bi);

//Get the Block of Pixels from memoryDC to the Screen

    dc.BitBlt(0,0,bi.bmWidth,bi.bmHeight,&bmDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    bmDC.SelectObject(pOldbmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalidate the window with [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that it repaints itself. In the `WM_PAINT` handler, you need to convert the die number to a resource ID. Then you load the bitmap from the resources with `LoadImage`. Create a memory DC and select the bitmap into it, then use `BitBlt` to copy it to the window.

Comment: @Mac the code you have looks like a good start. Instead of putting it in the OnBnClicked handler, put it in the OnPaint handler. You won't need a CClientDC because you'll get one automatically in OnPaint.

Comment: @Mac as I said, you call InvalidateRect and the OnPaint will get called as a result of that.